# Reading and matching contents of two big files

Tags: java

I have two files each having the same format with approximately 100,000 lines. For each line in file one I am extracting the second component or column and if I find a match in the second column of second file, I extract their third components and combine them, store or output it.

Though my implementation works but the programs runs extremely slow, it takes more than an hour to iterate over the files, compare and output all the results.

I am reading and storing the data of both files in ArrayList then iterate over those list and do the comparison. Below is my code, is there any performance related glitch or its just normal for such an operation.

Note : I was using String.split() but I understand form other post that StringTokenizer is faster.

```
public ArrayList<String> match(String file1, String file2) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<String> finalOut = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ArrayList<String> data = readGenreDataIntoMemory(file1);
            ArrayList<String> data1 = readGenreDataIntoMemory(file2);
            StringTokenizer st = null;

            for(String line : data){
                HashSet<String> genres = new HashSet<>();
                boolean sameMovie = false;
                String movie2 = "";
                st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
                //String line[] = fline.split("\\|");
                String ratingInfo = st.nextToken();
                String movie1 = st.nextToken();
                String genreInfo = st.nextToken();
                if(!genreInfo.equals("null")){
                    for(String s : genreInfo.split(",")){
                        genres.add(s);
                    }
                }


                StringTokenizer st1 = null;
                for(String line1 : data1){
                    st1 = new StringTokenizer(line1, "|");
                    st1.nextToken();
                    movie2 = st1.nextToken();
                    String genreInfo2= st1.nextToken();
                    //If the movie name are similar then they should have the same genre
                    //Update their genres to be the same
                    if(!genreInfo2.equals("null") && movie1.equals(movie2)){
                        for(String s : genreInfo2.split(",")){
                            genres.add(s);
                        }
                        sameMovie = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(sameMovie){
                    finalOut.add(ratingInfo+""+movieName+""+genres.toString()+"\n");
                }else if(sameMovie ==  false){
                    finalOut.add(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalOut;
    }
```

Comment: for every line in your first file you are reading 8and processing) from the beginning the contents of the second file.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, that is what I am doing. For each line in in the first file compare it to all the lines in the second file and if certain match are found then do some action. This is evident from my code. But its very slow.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it 100000*100000 times.

Comment: Yes this is right, O(n^2) operation.

Comment: Is there a requirement to write the application yourself? There are any number of programs that exist that do this very efficiently.

Comment: I am just more familiar with Java. but I feel there might be a way to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Streams API

```
String file1 = "files1.txt";
String file2 = "files2.txt";
// get all the lines by movie name for each file.
Map<String, List<String[]>> map = Stream.of(Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)),
                                            Files.lines(Paths.get(file2)))
        .flatMap(p -> p)
        .parallel()
        .map(s -> s.split("[|]", 3))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(sa -> sa[1], Collectors.toList()));

// merge all the genres for each movie.
map.forEach((movie, lines) -> {
    Set<String> genres = lines.stream()
            .flatMap(l -> Stream.of(l[2].split(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println("movie: " + movie + " genres: " + genres);
});
```

This has the advantage of being `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)` and it's multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do a hash join.

As of now you are doing an outer loop join which is O(n^2), the hash join will be amortized O(n)

Put the contents of each file in a hash map, with key the field you want (second field).

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
// build the map from file1
```

Then do the hash join

```
   for(String key1 : map1.keySet()){
        if(map2.containsKey(key1)){
        // do your thing you found the match
        }
    }
```